# APK Expansion Files for different screen resolutions

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

My application requires 50MB+ of images for it to run properly. I was planing to provide different resolutions of images for different screen. The version of images are 1080p, 720p and 480p images in order to support more screens.
Is it possible to use the APK Expansion Files to host and download the files based on the screen resolution?